# How can I set focus to an input box with a mouse click in AutoIT

Tags: click, focus, autoit

I am attempting to create a GUI that prompts the user for 3 strings to be used as variables for later on in the script.

My question is in regard to the ControlFocus command.

I have 3 input boxes.  I can cycle through them with the "Tab" key with no problems.  Is there a way to link a mouse left click to the ControlFocus command to set focus on whichever input box is clicked?
I would like for the user to be able to choose the input box of their choice by simply clicking it rather than scrolling through them with the tab key.

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

; GUI
GUICreate("Adam's Instance Bot", 200, 210)

; LABEL
$Label_1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Username", 30, 20, 100, 20)
$Label_2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password", 30, 60, 100, 20)
$Label_3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Instance", 30, 100, 100, 20)

; Input
$Input_1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 80, 20, 90, 20)
$Input_2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 80, 60, 90, 20)
$Input_3 = GUICtrlCreateInput ("", 80, 100, 90, 20)

; BUTTON
$RUN_1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start bot", 20, 140, 160, 50)

; Run script with variables
GUISetState()
While 1
    $MSG = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $MSG = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
         Case $MSG = $RUN_1
           $username = GUICtrlRead($Input_1)
           $password = GUICtrlRead($Input_2)
           $instance = GUICtrlRead($Input_3)
           MsgBox(0,"text blah", $password )
    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Am I going the wrong route trying to use the ControlFocus command?  Is there a better way?  Is this much easier than I am making it?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always select the input boxes by a mouseclick, but you created Labels on top of them so you click the label and not the box. 
Just change the label width to ~50 and it will work.

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

; GUI
GUICreate("Adam's Instance Bot", 200, 210)

; LABEL
$Label_1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Username", 30, 20, 50, 20)
$Label_2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password", 30, 60, 50, 20)
$Label_3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Instance", 30, 100, 50, 20)

; Input
$Input_1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 80, 20, 90, 20)
$Input_2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 80, 60, 90, 20)
$Input_3 = GUICtrlCreateInput ("", 80, 100, 90, 20)

; BUTTON
$RUN_1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start bot", 20, 140, 160, 50)

; Run script with variables
GUISetState()
While 1
    $MSG = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $MSG = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
         Case $MSG = $RUN_1
           $username = GUICtrlRead($Input_1)
           $password = GUICtrlRead($Input_2)
           $instance = GUICtrlRead($Input_3)
           MsgBox(0,"text blah", $password )
    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Comment: Haaa!  Thanks again man!  I was beginning to get worried.  Worked like a charm.